# How do I multiply a variable by itself?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

I am very new (as in one day) to python and cannot figure it out.

```
A = raw_input ("Enter A length - ")
B = raw_input ("Enter B length - ")
C = raw_input ("Enter C length - ")
if A*A + B*B > C*C:
```

As you can see above, I am trying to multiply 'A' by itself and then 'b' by itself and then see if it is less than C multiplied by itself. 
Probably really simple, but I cannot find it in my Python book or online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `int` to convert the numbers into integers because `raw_input` returns a string.

```
A = int(raw_input("Enter A length - "))
B = int(raw_input("Enter B length - "))
C = int(raw_input("Enter C length - "))

if A * A + B * B > C * C:
    # do stuff
```

What `int` does is take an object and convert it into an integer. Before, `raw_input` returned a string. You need to cast to integer with `int`.

```
>>> A = raw_input('Test: ')
Test: 3
>>> A
'3'
```

As you can see, `raw_input` returns a string. Convert to integer:

```
>>> int(A)
3
```

Note: `input` is not a good idea as it evaluates input taken as literal code. This can raise many errors for wrong inputs—`NameError` to name one. It can also be dangerous in the sense that malicious code can be executed by the user. **Also, for handling wrong inputs, use a try/except**. It will raise a `ValueError` if the object passed is not convertible.

Answer (score 0):

```
#here you can see we put "int" infront. this is called converting
#since inputs are always strings, we are converting the input into integer
A = int(raw_input ("Enter A length - "))
B = int(raw_input ("Enter B length - "))
C = int(raw_input ("Enter C length - "))

#here we multiply the inputs beforehand
A = A * A
B = B * B
C = C * C

#result variable = A and B combined.
result = A + B

#if we input A = 2 B = 2 C = 5
print(A) #=4
print(B) #=4
print(C) #=25

if (result > C):
    print('A and B are bigger than C')
else: #<---- so this will be called. since 4+4=8 while C=25.
    print('A and B are smaller than C')
```